# IPX/SPX networking on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, networking

I have a certain old program that needs to use IPX for networking.  It is being used with the [Hamachi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi) VPN software (which does support IPX/SPX). I found [this site](http://www.starbase01.com/site/index.php?id=22,87,0,0,1,0) that shows how to get the IPX/SPX protocol on Vista, but for my case it isn't good enough because I also need to be able to change the settings. Is there any other way to get it working on Vista?

The alternative is for me to install Windows 95 in a VM. How would I go about setting up a Windows 95 VM to use IPX over a network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently **there aren't** any fixes to install a fully function IPX/SPX networking protocol under Vista or Windows 7. The best you can get is the hack you see on that link.

A VM may or may not be a good alternative depending on what you need to do. A good VM is **VMWare**, but this isn't a free program. You can however install Windows 9x with IPX/SPX support.

A free alternative is going the emulator way with **DOSBox**. You can now install Windows95 on it and it also includes support for IPX/SPX.

Personally, if I were you I'd go the DOSbox way before considering VMWare. VMWare support for DOS based virtual machines isn't brilliant anyways and DOSBox makes a much better job at emulating a DOS environment with support for different types of hardware. Until recently installing windows 95 with it was a challenge. But not anymore.

Comment: please comment why you downvote an answer, if you feel it is wrong somehow.

Comment: +1 vmware player is free.  apparently the 3.0 RC can create VMs -- it's in beta but that might be good enough.  don't know if 95/98 is supported though. http://communities.vmware.com/community/beta/player

Comment: oops ... i'll have to owe ya one, i'm at the limit.

Comment: I'd suggest Micros~1 Virtual PC as a VM. It may suck for Linux, but it runs Windows and MS-DOS perfectly.

Comment: The program in question was Theme Hospital. Conviently, the disc includes both the DOS and Windows versions so DOSBox was perfect (VMWare runs rather slowly on my PC).

Answer (score 1):

Without official support I doubt you'll ever find a serious solution, unfortunately.

I've tried the solution you mentioned before to play Command & Conquer: Red Alert 2 game, which uses IPX rather than IP, and I could NOT manage to make it work, after that, I've found a patch to use the more modern IP.

I'd go with the second choice, install an OS that supports IPX natively in a VM.
Windows 98 does support IPX, and configuring it should be quite straightforward.

Not very helpful answer, so I made it CW ;)

Comment: I broke out the old C&C Red Alert too only to be completely dismayed at it's reliance on IPX, I must have spent days trying to figure out a way to get it to work...